# Deploying a subdirectory of a repo using capistrano

Tags: git, capistrano, capistrano3, middleman

I have a static site built with middleman. The files are in the 'build' directory. I have the entire directory structure in my git repo but I just want to deploy the 'build' folder to the server.
I added `set :repo_tree, 'build'` to my deploy.rb but I get the error

```
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: path not found: build
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

what am I doing wrong?
( I'm using capistrano version 3.4.0 )